# How can I save my panda's dataframe to a sqlite3 database while preserving the datetime as the indentifier?

Tags: python, sqlite

When I create the dataset originally it has the first column as a Date

```
print("saving this training set for " + symbol)
print (thisDataset)
dbHelper.saveTrainingSet(thisDataset, symbol)
```

In dbHelper:

```
def saveTrainingSet(trainingSet, symbol):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('my_database')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trainingsets_' + symbol + ' (' + readColumnsForSaving() +')')
    conn.commit()
    trainingSet.to_sql('trainingsets_' + symbol, conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
```

[image]

When I load the dataset, it no longer has the dates as the identifier column.  How can I preserve it?

```
returnedTrainingset = dbHelper.getTrainingSet(symbol)
print(returnedTrainingset)
```

In dbHelper:

```
def getTrainingSet(symbol):
conn = sqlite3.connect('technical_analysis_database')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM trainingsets_' + symbol)
return pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=[readColumnsForLoading())
```

[image]

The column list is long so I just replaced it with 2 different readColumns...() method placeholders.  Neither column string contains the Date column (when I tried adding it to both, the one for loading threw an exception saying their was 1 too many columns.

How can I save the original dataset including the date identifier column to a sqlite3 database table?  And how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify,

```
trainingSet.to_sql(...
```

to

```
trainingSet.reset_index().to_sql(...)
# or
# trainingSet.to_sql(..., index=True)
```